# Power of number close to 1

Tags: r, floating-point, floating-point-precision, numerical-stability

I'm guessing there is some standard trick that I wasn't able to find: Anyway I want to compute a large power of a number very close to 1(think 1-p where p<1e-17) in a numerically stable fashion. 1-p is truncated to 1 on my system.

Using the taylor expansion of the logarithm I obtain the following bounds

[image: formula]

Is there anything smarter I can do?

Comment: One alternative is since (1-x^-1)^x tends to 1/e as x gets large, you could use this to compute it as a power of 1/e.

Comment: @James Would this not lead to the same approximation as my upper bound. That is (1-p)^n = [[1-1/(1/p)]^(1/p)]^(np) approximately (1/e)^np

Comment: Ah, yes. If p is small, p^2 is very small, so I think you can safely use exp(-np). The lower bound can be rewritten as exp(-np)^(1+p/2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may calculate `log(1+x)` more accurately for `|x| <= 1` by using the `log1p` function.

An example:

```
> p <- 1e-17
> log(1-p)
[1] 0
> log1p(-p)
[1] -1e-17
```

And another one:

```
> print((1+1e-17)^100, digits=22)
[1] 1
> print(exp(100*log1p(-1e-17)), digits=22)
[1] 0.9999999999999990007993
```

Here, however, we're limited with the accuracy of `double` type-based FP arithmetic (see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)).

Another way is to use e.g. the `Rmpfr` (a.k.a. Multiple Precision Floating-Point Reliable) package:

```
> options(digits=22)
> library(Rmpfr)
> .N <- function(.) mpfr(., precBits = 200) # see the package's vignette
> (1-.N(1e-20))^100
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 0.99999999999999999900000000000000005534172854579042829381053529
```

The package uses the `gsl` and `mpfr` library to implement arbitrary precision FP operations (at the cost of slower computation speed, of course).

Comment: Cool I did not know of log1p. It would be nice if there was some algebraic workaround, where arbitrary precision was not needed.

Comment: Having in mind [this paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), I think it will be difficult to find any workaround... It's a general computational limitation.